# how to add a custom header to google oauth callback request

Tags: google-oauth

I'm using a jwt based authentication system and I'd like to ensure that google sends this token back in the header. Is there anyway to give google custom headers to send back to a server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in the header, but you can use the state param to include it in the URL.

Comment: oh please I need this. Do you have some example or guide how to achieve that?